# Broken dependencies when installing CodeLite 8 on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation

I want to install CodeLite.  I followed the instructions on the website.

Because I'm running Linux Mint 17.1 x64, I added repositories for ubuntu utopic, trusty and vivid universe.

Now when I run `apt install codelite wxcrafter` I get:

```
 codelite : depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.41.1) but 2.40.2 is installed instead-0ubuntu1  

            depends: libhunspell-1.3-0 (>= 1.3.3)but 1.3.2-6ubuntu2 is installed instead
            depends: liblldb-3.4 but is not installable
            depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is installed instead
            suggests: nodejs but is not going to be installed
```

I tried the answer on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330268/how-to-install-codelite-on-ubuntu) question but the links given are broken.

I think the problem is that some dependencies are either new for my Mint (aka libglib2) or somewhat old (aka liblldb).

I can see liblldb-3.5 with `apt-cache search`. 
Installing it didn't remove "depends: liblldb-3.4" line.

I tried looking for libglib2.0-0. 
I found version 2.44 on Debian's page and downloaded it,
but installing it has broken my system and I had to format my hard drive.

So what to do to install CodeLite 8 on Linux Mint 17.1 64-bit Cinnamon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mint 17.1 use http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ trusty universe

In terms of the steps,

1. Remove all other codelite repos from
   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list
2. Add the proper repo: sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ trusty universe'
3. Update sources: sudo apt-get update
4. Install codelite: sudo apt-get install codelite

This should install all dependencies and codelite properly.

Comment: codelite is found in the main repositories, right Now I don't have any PPA or additional repo that contains it, do I just remove the main repositories ? Can I remove an entry from a repository ?

Comment: according to your OP you have added both the utopic and trusty repos. That might not work well in terms of getting all dependencies sorted. I would check the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list and make sure there is only one entry similar to deb http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ trusty universe